# How can I send push notifications to an outlook add-in from a web server?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

### Problem

I can't seem to find a reference a suggested way to implement sending notifications from a web server to an outlook add-in.

I've looked on:

- the officeJS docs, which have a deprecated entry about notifications [rest api v2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/notify-rest-operations), pointing to the [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/notifications-concept-overview), which again is deprecated (but without pointing to any up to date version)
- stackoverflow, but the questions were either [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50276462/can-an-outlook-js-add-in-receive-push-notifications-from-an-external-server-usin), or, [answering the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435061/outlook-365-keeping-specific-events-in-sync-with-external-system?rq=1) with the deprecated notifications api
- the officejs Q&A forum, where someone [pointed out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/266097/push-notification-practices.html) the Azure Notifications Hub service, but only linked to an android example; but the [docs state that it's primarily made to send messages to mobile devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/) officejs add-ins as a tutorial or reference

Could you help me understand what's the best way to implement push notifications from web server -> outlook add-in?

### Context

- I personally would like to use Firebase Cloud Messaging, which depends on the [Push API](https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/) under the hood. Is the Push API supported?
- WebSockets could also work, but here again I wasn't able to find something before working away on an implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@nickromano is correct in that an add-in is just a webpage embedded in Outlook, so you may be able to send data to it through websockets or long polling outside of a standard request. However, this is not a supported use case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Web add-ins are not run all the time in Outlook. They are activated in reaction to any event or by users (for example, when a task pane is opened). Moreover, Outlook add-ins are working under the context of the currently selected item(s) only. So, your add-in should be activated if you want to receive any push notifications (by opening a task pane or any event).

Be aware, feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: “Type: product feature request” at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. My question is actually when the add-in's context is live, how should/can I send push notifications to it?
Not all browser APIs are supported, the [Notification API](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2747) specifically didn't work in my case.

Comment: Since it's just a webpage embedded in Outlook, if you're looking to communicate with your Addin while it's open you could use websockets or long polling to send data to the client outside of a standard request. If you don't have much experience setting that up in your backend you could always try an off-the-shelf solution like PubNub channels to play around with it.